# How to solve the following equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Hey my book has solved the following equation in a different way can someone please explain how to.
I couldnt understand how to solve it.
Please check the image below
[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vbts2.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdWg5.jpg)

Comment: First of all, please include your attempts in the question. Second of all, I don't think we have enough information to be able to help you; what are you trying to find? What is A?

Comment: What about the sentence that is cut off? I think there is additional important information

Comment: There isn't anything related to the equation.

Comment: This us the full one http://i.imgur.com/M5O8977.jpg

Comment: So, where is your problem? If you don't know the cross multiplication method, then From the second equation, you get $y=m_1x$, now substitute this in the first equation. You get, $x(l+mm_1)=-n\implies x=\frac{-n}{l+mm_1}$. Then $y=m_1x=\frac{-nm_1}{l+mm_1}$ .

Comment: Well well I'm confused from Let A be the point of intersection of lx+my+n=0......  To similarly ,by solving lx+my+n=0 the part in between is what is making me real confused how did they solve lx+my+n=0 and m1x-y+0=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some funny notations like $\;l(0)\;,\;\;m_1\;$ and the method seems a little confusing, so I'd do it as follows:

$$\begin{cases}lx+my=-n\\m_1x-y=0\end{cases}\stackrel{\color{green}{\text{mult. 2nd eq. by}\;m}}\implies\begin{cases}&lx&+&my=-n\\&m_1mx&-&my=\;\;0\end{cases}\stackrel{\color{green}{\text{add both eq's.}}}\implies$$

$$\implies(l+m_1m)x=-n\implies \color{red}{x=-\frac n{l+m_1m}}$$

Now substitute the above in the second original equation (easier option):

$$m_1\left(-\frac n{l+m_1m}\right)-y=0\implies \color{red}{y=-\frac{m_1n}{l+m_1m}}$$

All the above under the assumption that $\;l+m_1m\neq0\;$ , of course.

Comment: Thanks ,that really helped.Well I'm from Andhra Pradesh,India the text books and guides are subpar. i already Knew this method but was totally confused due that notations.